# How to implement a coalesce partition for DataSource V2 write

Tags: apache-spark, datasource

I'm implementing a DataSource to write data to our system from spark, and want to provide a configuration `numPartitions` to users to determine the number of partitions used for parallelism writing. It's similar to the [`numPartitions` of JDBC datasource](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html).

I have learned [the implementation of JDBC](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala#L877), and it's like this `dataframe.coalesce(numPartitions).rdd.foreachPartition`. But I'm using DataSource V2 API, and not sure **how to implement a coalesce repartition**. I have found that I can implement the interface [`RequiresDistributionAndOrdering`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/connector/write/RequiresDistributionAndOrdering.java) to set the number of partitions, but how to define a coalesce [Distribution](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/connector/distributions/Distribution.java)?